# Arity Overloading in Clojure

Tags: clojure, arity

Why is the following function not working in Clojure:

```
(defn tests
  [] 0
  [a b] 1)
```

It gives the following error: `clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each needs to be surrounded by parentheses

```
(defn tests 
  ([] 0) 
  ([a b] 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than 2x var's, use `& more:`

```
(defn maxz
  "Returns the greatest of the nums."
  ([x] x)
  ([x y] (if (> x y) x y))
  ([x y & more]
   (reduce maxz (maxz x y) more)))
```

> (maxz 1 2 3 4 5 100 6)
>
> => 100